# Visual Studio Component Cache Out of Date

Tags: visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Almost every time I try to run the update-database command for EF migrations, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015:

> Exception calling "GetService" with "1" argument(s): "Exception
>   calling "Invoke" with "2" argument(s): "The Visual Studio component
>   cache is out of date. Please restart Visual Studio. The Visual Studio
>   component cache is out of date. Please restart Visual Studio."" At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1004
>   char:5
>   +     $packageInstallerServices = $componentModel.GetService([NuGet.Vis ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ScriptMethodRuntimeException   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:1006
>   char:5
>   +     $vsPackage = $packageInstallerServices.GetInstalledPackages() | ? ...
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:713
>   char:28
>   +     $toolsPath = Join-Path $installPath tools
>   +                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:780
>   char:74
>   + ...  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom((Join-Path $ToolsPath EntityF ...
>   +                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>   You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:781
>   char:5
>   +     $dispatcher = $utilityAssembly.CreateInstance(
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull   Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. At
>   D:\Dev\Project\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\EntityFramework.psm1:810
>   char:20
>   +         (Join-Path $runner.ToolsPath EntityFramework.PowerShell.dll),
>   +                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

- Most of the time restarting Visual Studio 2015 will fix this, but sometimes I have to clear the component cache manually by removing all items from C:\Users{UserName}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
- I do run VS2015 as administrator.

Comment: This could be a known bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1663079/the-visual-studio-component-cache-is-out-of-date-please-restart-visual-studio. I suggest you to reinstall Visual Studio using the new release Update 1 ISO. Clean all temp file and "uninstall force".

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. If I download the visual studio community from visualstudio.com, do I get the Update 1 ISO?

Comment: I'm not sure that, There is a link to download here, have a try https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: I was going to suggest you check for updates.

Comment: Have you gotten anywhere with this?

Comment: I completely removed VS2015 and reinstalled using the link from visualstudio.com (which includes sp1).  I did that twice.

when I open the project now, I get a new error (`Set-DefaultScaffolder : Cannot get an instance of EnvDTE.DTE`)

Comment: and after that I again the The Visual Studio component cache is out of date error. Which means I will probably try to reinstall Windows and if that doesn't work I'll become a PHP programmer I think ... :)

The error is about appinsights (which I don't need): `Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.ZeroClickLogging.NLogLoggingFramework.ctor(serviceProvider): expected exactly 1 export of System.IServiceProvider but found 0.
   part definition Microsoft.AppInsights.GettingStarted.ZeroClickLogging.NLogLoggingFramework`

Answer (score 14):

You should go to

```
%APPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Visual Studio\<version>
```

and delete the ComponentModelChache directory.

Comment: This is very true. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error when trying to select records in my SQL server management studio:

**Error:** "The Visual Studio component cache is out of date. Please restart Visual Studio. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting)"

I restarted Visual Studio but got same error.

**Solution:** I went to this location: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache"

And deleted all the files inside that folder and restarted both VS and SQL server. IT WORKED!

Comment: I got the same issue, however instead of deleting files I just closed Visual Studio and restarted SQL server management studio. That did the trick for me