# Visual Studio 2017 throws error when clicking "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." in context menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I right click in a .cs file and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." in the context menu I get an error popup which reads:

> The Visual Studio component cache is out of date (assembly: Text.CSharp.Analyzers, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35). Please restart Visual Studio.

I have tried clearing the Windows `%Temp%` directory via "Disk Cleanup" tool, and even tried updating Visual Studio to the latest version without any success.

I am currently on version 15.7.4.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Also, try running Visual Studio in administrator mode.

Comment: Turning what off and on exactly?

Comment: I do not know exactly how to fix this issue, but It is always a good idea to restart visual studio, clean and rebuild the solution, and if all else fails try restarting the computer

Comment: We'll have to assume you tried restarting VS.  It is the kind of problem you'd get when an update did not go well and an old version of a component stayed behind without getting updated.  Pretty safe to assume you have to re-install.  Check the disk health first, at least run chkdsk.exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No solutions were working so I opened the Visual Studio Installer app and did a repair install of Visual Studio. After a restart now the errors have gone away and the "Quick Actions and Refactorings..." action is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try manually clearing the Temp folder, without using a tool.

1. Press the Windows Key + R to open the RUN window.
2. In the RUN Window,type %TMP% and click "OK"
3. Delete all of the contents of this folder.

Are you by any chance using SQL Server Management Studio? If you are, that might be connected to the error.

Comment: I tried manually clearing the Temp folder and restarting VS2017 but the result was the same. I do have SQL Server Management Studio installed but it's not open at the time of the error though.

Comment: Okay, try something similar, but clear both: C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Roaming\Temp, try looking in C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Clear both of those paths

Comment: I don't seem to have a folder `\AppData\Roaming\Temp`?

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio version 15.7.5 is released sometime back. Update to it.

Also clear `temp` folder and `prefetch` folders along with `%temp%` folder.

It should solve the issue.

Comment: Win+R --> Type `prefetch` --> redirects to **C:\Windows\Prefetch** delete all, (*it requires admin rights*). If this doesnt work and you have tried modifying Visual studio installation , I think you need to do complete uninstall and then reinstall of the product

Comment: BTW did you try this [visual-studio-component-cache-out-of-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861963/visual-studio-component-cache-out-of-date)

Comment: I tried deleting `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache` as instructed in that question and it didn't solve the issue

Comment: weird. I think your VS is corrupted while installation or upgrade. Uninstall and install it again.